# smart contract and just buying ETH

Tags: exchanges

I bought ETH from Coinmama against USD and wanted it to be sent to Huobi exchange 3 hours late - ETH still has not hit the exchange.

Huobi are saying they are ETH smart contracts and they cant accept them - i go  back to coinmama and they dont know what to do ... How do I fix this ,

you help would be most appreciated

Comment: how is this related to cpp-ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

First, please be very careful.

Second, nothing I say here is advice of any sort and shouldn’t be taken as such.

Third, you need to establish your own wallet and send the ether to that wallet, and then interact with the smart contract.

I’m specifically not including information on how to do that here to protect myself.